# In python how do i get the size (width,height) of a gtk label?

Tags: python, gtk

I have looked all over for this but can't find an answer that works.

```
element.get_allocation().y returns -1
element.get_allocation().height returns 1
```

This is the code im using to create the label

```
item_link_summary = Gtk.Label(item_summary)
item_link_summary.show()
self.layout1.put(item_link_summary, 0, top)
print item_link_summary.get_allocation().y
```

Comment: Although you called `show`, you can't get the size until the widget has been both realized and laid out. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675514/totally-fed-up-with-get-gtk-widget-height-and-width

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how much space the label requires, you can use the `size_request` method, which returns a tuple `(width, height)`.  If you want to know how much space it is being given, you have to wait until it is realized.  This means until it and all of its ancestors, including the toplevel window, are shown.  Usually that means after `window.show_all()` is executed.  After that, you can use `label.get_allocation().width` and `label.get_allocation().height`.