# How to find the coordinate of a glade viewport in gtk c

Tags: c, coordinates, glade, gtk2

Is there any way of finding the coordinate of a viewport in glade window... fullscreen coordinates are not so hard to find but it I want to find in a small area(it can be anywhere in the window)...the how will I do it??

Comment: I got my answer here...the height and width of a widget anywhere...now i can find my coordinates.                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675514/totally-fed-up-with-get-gtk-widget-height-and-width

Comment: You can anwer your own question. Gives you some points and keeps so organized.

Comment: @tobias47n9e It took time for me to find what I exactly wanted...but Yes the above link did help :)