# How to refresh, redraw a window (widget) in gtk?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk2

I am using Opensuse 13.1 Linux Os. I am new to gtk2 and c. I am trying to create a application that can place a button on a table which is attached as per the values typed by the user. My program code is as following

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *value1, *value2, *value3, *value4;
} entrygrouped;

guint ival1, ival2, ival3, ival4;

void button_clicked(entrygrouped *widget)
{
    const gchar *value1, *value2, *value3, *value4;

    value1 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(widget->value1));
    value2 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(widget->value2));
    value3 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(widget->value3));
    value4 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(widget->value4));

    ival1 = (guint)atoi(value1);
    ival2 = (guint)atoi(value2);
    ival3 = (guint)atoi(value3);
    ival4 = (guint)atoi(value4);

    g_print("ENTRY VALUES = %s %s %s %s\n", value1, value2, value3, value4);
    g_print("ENTRY NUMS = %d %d %d %d\n", ival1, ival2, ival3, ival4);
}

int main (int argc, char *args[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *vbox, *uptable, *downtable, *label;
    GtkWidget  *button, *button2;
    gtk_init(&argc, &args);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_get_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window));

    entrygrouped *eg;
    eg = g_slice_new(entrygrouped);

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 2);
    uptable = gtk_table_new (3, 4, FALSE);
    downtable = gtk_table_new (3, 3, TRUE);

    label = gtk_label_new (" Enter the values to position the widget ");
    eg->value1 = gtk_entry_new();
    eg->value2 = gtk_entry_new();
    eg->value3 = gtk_entry_new();
    eg->value4 = gtk_entry_new();
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Submit");
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("BUTTON");

    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), label, 0, 3, 0, 1);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), eg->value1, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), eg->value2, 1, 2, 1, 2);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), eg->value3, 0, 1, 2, 3);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), eg->value4, 1, 2, 2, 3);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), button, 1, 2, 3, 4);

    gtk_widget_queue_draw(GTK_WIDGET(window));

    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(downtable), button2, ival1, ival2,
                                                                ival3, ival4);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), uptable, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), downtable, 0, 0, 0);


    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked",
                                G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), eg);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
                                G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Now whenever i open my application from terminal and enter some values and hit submit button, values are printed on terminal, but the problem is window did not draw the button2 with newly assigned values. I dont know any function which can refresh or redraw the whole window, though i tried the

```c
while (gtk_events_pending())
  gtk_main_iteration();
```

above the button2 table attachment still i window do nothing.
Do i need another callback function to resize window? Please help me with this problem.

EDIT :
 If my question is unclear i want to show it graphical way as follows

```c
 ----------------------------
| a.out             _ [ ] x  |
 ----------------------------               before entering the 
| -------------------------- |              values 
||            |             ||
| -------------------------- |
||            |             ||
| -------------------------- |
|                   ________ |
|                  | Submit ||
|                   -------- |
 ----------------------------

 ----------------------------
| a.out             _ [ ] x  |
 ----------------------------               after entering the 
| -------------------------- |              values 
||           0 |          1 ||               
| -------------------------- |              button2 widget should be 
||           0 |          1 ||              redrawn according to the
| -------------------------- |              values entered and window
|                   ________ |              widget should be updated 
|                  | Submit ||
|                   -------- | 
|   _________                |
|  |  Button |               |
|   ---------                |
 ----------------------------
```

Comment: You have alot of problems in there try to fix them before. Compile with "-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion --std=c11  -Og  `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`" to see them.

Comment: thanx for the comment Michi, but i am currently working this application on gtk2. sorry for the gtk3 tags.

Comment: What you want to do is unclear. Do you want to resize the `button2` from numerical x,y,w,h values entered in `eg`? Please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: Why don't you use GTK3 for your new code? It is known to have improved the widget layout code...

Comment: You really need to read a lot more about C programming and about GTK. That would take you several weeks of work. Don't expect us to code your program in your place (and you should use GTK3).

Comment: sorry for my question Basile, i tried to google the keywords like 'redrawing the widget' and 'updating the widget' and also 'refreshing gtk window', i also have Devhelp but i don't know what to search in it, i tried 'draw', 'redraw', 'resize' keywords in it, thats why i came here. I think i need to learn more about gtk signals and callbacks. but because i am newbie could you guys give me a link which can help me about this program pls?

Comment: There is a lot of documentation and several books on GTK (but you should target GTK3, not GTK2)

Answer (score 1):

You never changed the label of the `button2`.

You should have some callback calling [gtk_button_set_label](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-label) on `button2` ; if you want to resize the widget you may need to send the [size-request](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-size-request) signal and/or [size-allocate](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-size-allocate) and/or the [check-resize](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkContainer.html#GtkContainer-check-resize) signal on the container. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2675514/841108) thread.

BTW, you really should use [GTK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) in new code (since GTK3 improved a lot on widget layout w.r.t. GTK2). And you'll better first code something simpler, to understand the [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) of GTK. You'll need to use the `gdb` [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) (and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) should be useful too).

Don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info when compiling (with e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wstring-prototypes -g`)

As you guessed, you need much more [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) (and [signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html) and slots) functions. Understanding what [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) are and what [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) is should be useful (because callbacks are related to continuations).

Comment: Thanx for replay, but i dont want to change the label of the button2 i want to position the button2 and update or refresh all window, once i enter the values.

Comment: Please improve your question, don't add comments.

Comment: You need to use `size-request` signal

Answer (score 1):

After lots reading and frustration i finally able to solve my answer, The purpose of my application is to know how the table attachment works.

1. Thus i did simple solution for problem. Which is attaching new button to a dialog box, Which is invoked after "clicked" event, the callback is as follows

```c
static void fundia(GtkButton *button, GtkWindow *parent)
{
    GtkWidget *dialog, *table, *button2;
    dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ("Information", parent,
                            GTK_DIALOG_MODAL, GTK_STOCK_OK, GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
                            NULL);
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("BUTTON");

    table = gtk_table_new (3, 3, TRUE);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), button2, ival1, ival2,
                                    ival3, ival4);
    gtk_box_pack_start_defaults (GTK_BOX(GTK_DIALOG(dialog)->vbox), table);
    gtk_widget_show_all(dialog);

    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}
```

where the callback function statement in main() is

`g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(fundia), (gpointer) window);`

Though this function serves my purpose but above solution is irrelevant to this post's question hence it did not reuse or redraw the widget.

2. Thus here is the final code of my program is as follows

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
gboolean buttonbool = FALSE;

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *value1, *value2, *value3, *value4;
} entrygrouped;

static GtkWidget *button2 = 0;

guint ival1, ival2, ival3, ival4;

void button_clicked (gpointer data, entrygrouped *widget)
{
    const gchar *cvalue1, *cvalue2, *cvalue3, *cvalue4;
    cvalue1 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(widget->value1));
    cvalue2 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(widget->value2));
    cvalue3 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(widget->value3));
    cvalue4 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(widget->value4));

    ival1 = (guint)atoi(cvalue1);
    ival2 = (guint)atoi(cvalue2);
    ival3 = (guint)atoi(cvalue3);
    ival4 = (guint)atoi(cvalue4);

    g_print("ENTRY VALUES = %s %s %s %s\n", cvalue1, cvalue2, cvalue3, cvalue4);
    g_print("ENTRY NUMS = %d %d %d %d\n", ival1, ival2, ival3, ival4);
}

void showid(gpointer data, GtkWidget *widget)
{
    if (buttonbool == TRUE)
    {
        /* Here reference count of the widget is decreased by 1. */
        gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(widget), GTK_WIDGET(button2));

        /* In below statement reference count of widget increased by 1 */
        g_object_ref(button2);
        button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("BUTTON");

        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(widget), button2, ival1, ival2,
                                                            ival3, ival4);
    } else {
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(widget), button2, ival1, ival2,
                                                            ival3, ival4);
        buttonbool = TRUE;
    }

    gtk_widget_show(button2);
}

int main (int argc, char *args[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *uptable, *downtable, *button, *vbox, *instr;

    gtk_init(&argc, &args);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW(window), "TABLEAPP");

    entrygrouped *eg;
    eg = g_slice_new(entrygrouped);

    instr = gtk_label_new (" Enter the values to position the widget ");
    uptable = gtk_table_new (2, 4, FALSE);
    downtable = gtk_table_new (3, 3, TRUE);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Submit");   // Button with label
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("SAME");
                                                    // Button with label
    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 2);                  // GTK vbox

    eg->value1 = gtk_entry_new();
    eg->value2 = gtk_entry_new();
    eg->value3 = gtk_entry_new();
    eg->value4 = gtk_entry_new();

    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), instr, 0, 3, 0, 1);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), eg->value1, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), eg->value2, 1, 2, 1, 2);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), eg->value3, 0, 1, 2, 3);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), eg->value4, 1, 2, 2, 3);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(uptable), button, 1, 2, 3, 4);

    /* The second arguments gtk_box_pack_start(); is about expand properties of
    widget which was set 0 and third is about allocation fill properties is also
    set 0 in my previous program. */
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), uptable, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), downtable, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked",
                            G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), eg);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked",
                            G_CALLBACK(showid), downtable);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
                                G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

**So I made following differences :-**

1. The `gtk_box_pack_start();` functions second and third arguments is related to expand and fill properties was set to 0 in my previous program that means i don't have allocated any extra space for it.
2. The button2 is only available to main(). Thus i declared the function above main() to accessible to all function.
3. After attaching the button2 to downtable widget, when next time i am trying to reattach button2 to the table it was giving me a gtk_table_attach assertion child->parent == NULL failed error. So the previous reference needed to be free, thus the function `gtk_container_remove()`is added in showid callback function to decrease the reference count by 1. And i reference it again by `g_object_ref` to increase the reference counter by 1 to reference the widget again.

I want to thank Basile and Michi for there help, it was so helpful for me.